# xslt output two xml elements(same name)

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
<bookstore>
  <book isbn="0321049314" year="2000" edition="6">
    <author firstname="Carole" lastname="Wade" />
    <author firstname="Carol" lastname="Tavris" />
    <publisher>Prentice Hall</publisher>
    <price currency="CAN">110.00</price>
  </book>
```

XSLT:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="bookstore/book">
                   Author(s):
                   <p>Publisher: <xsl:value-of select="publisher"/></p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I display two authors'names like this format:

Author(s):Carole,Wade 
Carol,Tavris

**The complete look will be:**

Book's name: Psychology

Description: Introductory level Pyschology course book

Course Applicability: PSYC1101

*Authors: //cant figure it out*

Publisher: Prentice Hall

Price: 110.00

Category: Pschology

Copies in stock: 10

Please help!Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use for each loop for author '' tag too in your xslt, it will take multiple(all) authors information from xml

Comment: I am not quite sure how to code it. Could you show me a example? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following outputs the authors, separated by spaces, each of them being "First, Last":

```
<p>
   <xsl:text>Author(s): </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="author!concat(@firstname, ', ', @lastname)"
                 separator=" "/>
</p>
```

If you don't use XSLT 3.0, you have to use `xsl:for-each` on the `author` elements, instead of using the `!` operator.  That, as well as configuring the `s` at the end of "Author:" in case of several of them, are left as an exercise ;-)